# How to sort line items by OrderLineStatus in XML when AMPScript is looping?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, xml, xmlparsing

How do I show only items with `OrderLineStatus` as **Shipped** and `@Published` as **false**? Right now no items are being populated.

Here is my xml based **AMPScript**:

```
%%[

IF IndexOf(@xml,"<Published>") > 0 THEN

    set @PublishedRowSet = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/Invoices/InvoiceDetail/Published",1)
    set @PublishedRows = RowCount(@PublishedRowSet)

    if @PublishedRows > 0 THEN 
        set @Published = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/Invoices/InvoiceDetail/Published",1),1),"value")
    else
        set @Published = ""
    endif   

ELSE

    set @Published = ""

ENDIF

/** Order Info Begins**/
IF IndexOf(@xml,"<ItemID>") > 0 THEN 

    set @ItemIDRowSet = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/ItemID",1)
    set @ItemIDRows = RowCount(@ItemIDRowSet)

    if @ItemIDRows > 0 THEN 
        set @ItemID = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/ItemID",1),1),"value")
    else
        set @ItemID = ""
    endif   

ELSE

    set @ItemID=''

ENDIF

IF IndexOf(@xml,"<ItemDescription>") > 0 THEN 
    set @ItemDescriptionRowSet = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/ItemDescription",1)
    set @ItemDescriptionRows = RowCount(@ItemDescriptionRowSet)

    if @ItemDescriptionRows > 0 THEN 
        set @ItemDescription = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/ItemDescription",1),1),"value")
    else
        set @ItemDescription = ""
    endif

ELSE

    set @ItemDescription=''

ENDIF

IF IndexOf(@xml,"<OrderedQty>") > 0 THEN 

    set @OrderedQtyRowSet = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/Quantity/OrderedQty",1)
    set @OrderedQtyRows = RowCount(@OrderedQtyRowSet)

    if @OrderedQtyRows > 0 THEN 
        set @OrderedQty = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/Quantity/OrderedQty",1),1),"value")
    else
        set @OrderedQty = ""
    endif

ELSE

    set @OrderedQty=''

ENDIF

IF IndexOf(@xml,"<ExtendedPrice>") > 0 THEN 

    set @ExtendedPriceRowSet = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/PriceInfo/ExtendedPrice",1)
    set @ExtendedPriceRows = RowCount(@ExtendedPriceRowSet)

    if @ExtendedPriceRows > 0 THEN 
        set @ExtendedPrice = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/PriceInfo/ExtendedPrice",1),1),"value")
    else
        set @ExtendedPrice = ""
    endif       

ELSE

    set @ExtendedPrice=''

ENDIF

/** Order Info  Ends**/

IF IndexOf(@xml,"<OrderLine>") > 0 THEN

    set @OrderLineRowSet = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/LineNumber",1)    
    set @OrderLineStatusRowSet = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/OrderLineStatus",1) 

    if @OrderLineStatusRowSet > 0 THEN
        set @OrderLineStatus = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/OrderLineStatus",1),1),"value")
        set @OrderLine = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"//tXML/Message/Order/OrderLines/OrderLine/LineNumber",1),1),"i")            
    else

    endif

ELSE

ENDIF                                                           

IF @OrderLineStatus == "Shipped" and @Published == "false" THEN   

    for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@OrderLineRowSet) do

        set @ItemID = Field(Row(@ItemIDRowSet,@i),"value")             
        set @url = Lookup("Product_Feed","BuyerURL","Variation",@ItemID)
        set @ImageURL = Lookup('Product_Feed','ImageURL','Variation',@ItemID)

]%%


HTML CODE HERE

%%[

    next @i
ENDIF                                           

]%%
```

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show sections with results, then you have to check the **rowcount()** to determine if a node exists in your XML -- just like you do in all of your other conditionals.

I'd also recommend setting variables for each rowset.

There's no sorting with AMPScript other than with [**LookupOrderedRows()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/lookuporderedrows/), but that doesn't apply in your case.

You can utilize an XSLT Portfolio item to do the ordering.  It'll definitely add a layer of complexity to your email, but there are all kinds of transformations you can do.  SFMC supports XPath 1.0, not 2.0, so keep that in mind.

Here's a simple example of the AMPScript side:

```
%%[

  set @xml = AttributeValue("xml")
  Set @xslt = GetPortfolioItem("OrderConfirmation")
  Set @l = Length(@xslt)

  set @regionRowSet = BuildRowSetFromXML(@xml,"/OrderConfirmation/Shipping/Warehouse",0)

  if rowcount(@regionRowSet) > 0 then

   set @row = row(@regionRowSet,1)
   set @warehouse = field(@row,"Value")
   set @regionID = 0

   if not empty(@warehouse) then

    if indexOf(@warehouse,"Casper") > 0  then
      set @regionID = 1
    elseif indexOf(@warehouse,"Cody") > 0 then
      set @regionID = 2
    elseif indexOf(@warehouse,"Jackson") > 0 then
      set @regionID = 3
    endif

   endif

  endif

]%%%%=TreatAsContent(TransformXML(@xml, Substring(@xslt, 0, @l)))=%%
```

**Reference**

- [**TransformXML**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/transformxml.htm)